# Refactor via regex help (c style to c# style)

Tags: c#, regex, refactoring, resharper

I'm converting some C code to C#, and all is going well, however i'd like to jiggle things around so that:

```
Util.SetStart(someObject, somePoint);
```

...gets refactored to:

```
someObject.StartPoint = somePoint;
```

I think this is more than resharper can handle, and it seems the perfect candidate for regex replacement, however my regex knowledge is limited. If i'm mistaken, and this can be done in Resharper, i'd love to know!

As a side note, if I could use LINQ in place of regex that'd be awesome.

Comment: Since StartPoint does not exist anywhere in the source text, I assume you have a lookup table of some sorts? This seems to be much more than simple string-replace can handle.

Comment: Supposing you can do this through a regex replacement. How do you intend to make it work in your IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't make clear how should be handled `Util`, `SetStart` and `StartPoint`, I handcoded them:

```
var pattern = @"Util.SetStart\(([^,\s]+)\s*,\s*([^,\s]+)\);";
var text = "Util.SetStart(someObject, somePoint);";

var a = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, m => m.Groups[1] + ".StartPoint = " + m.Groups[2]);
```

It shouldn't be too hard to include those 3 functions in the regex, but I don't know what is the pattern I should follow when renaming, for example, `SetStart` to `StartPoint`.

Comment: Brilliant - thanks. I was hoping to do it via find/replace, but i'll convert this to VB so I can use it as a macro. And yeah I was going to hard code depending on if it was SetStart or SetEnd or whatever - this was 99% of it is automated, I just needed a way to grab someObject and somePoint so I could shuffle them around.